# Informatica : "Unable to handle request because repository content do not exist" when starting the Integration service

Tags: informatica

I am facing below error when starting the PowerCenter Integration service on Informatica 9.6.1, the service fails and the following error message is displayed.

```
ERROR: "Unable to handle request because repository content do not exist" when starting the Integration service.
```

I have done research and i have changed the Repository to run Normal Mode and i have restarted both the Repository and Integration Services, but still it is not resolved.

Can anyone help on this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes small actions makes a big impact, please try to restart your machine. This looks like you have installed the software and never restarted the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Repo > Repository Properties > Operating Mode
Change this option from "Exclusive Mode" to "Normal Mode" and restart both Repository and Integration Services.